# post the headers with curl php

Tags: php, curl, header

when I post the reply in a forum, I use live http header to view parameter which used to post the reply.
but, the headers no parameter. but, there are some header like this:

```
Content-Length: 1115
-----------------------------5959623329472
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

the title of reply
-----------------------------5959623329472
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

the content of reply
```

how to post the headers with curl ? my code don't work

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('POST /post HTTP/1.1',
    'Referer: http://*****.n-stars.org/post?t=4221&mode=reply',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

    test lagi kk 2',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

    test lagi ya kk 8)' ));
```

please help me :D

Answer (score 0):

These are not headers, If you are trying to make multipart post request, this should be content of your request body. In headers you should only inform endpoint about multipart request and boundary between parts:

```
// Headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Referer: http://*****.n-stars.org/post?t=4221&mode=reply',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=5959623329472',
    'Content-Length: 1115'
));

// Body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
'--5959623329472
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

test lagi kk 2
--5959623329472
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

test lagi ya kk 8)
--5959623329472--'
);
```

More about multipart requests: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html

Comment: i've tried your code, but don't work for me. check this [link](http://pastebin.com/sVfJXdzY). the output show me that reply was success, but the reply is not posted in forum

Comment: The question is about issuing multipart request with curl, not about posting to forum. Forums usually have implemented features to prevent automatic posting, so you may need more than this to post on the forums.

Comment: ok, i'm understand. thank for your help. i will more explore your code